# OneDrive for business custom hash function

Tags: onedrive-for-business

OneDrive 365 propose only QuickXorHash as a hashing algorithm. The goal is to reduce data transfer load; I am investing some time to try to set rules in order to use [perceptual hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) function for some media files before upload. Is this possible in OneDrive ? I came across [rclone](https://rclone.org/) but it seems to follow remote rules regarding hashes. If not, probably other solution to custom hash on client that could at least communicate with OneDrive ? Then I probably see how to proceed with a database of hashes of files uploaded in my company group.

Comment: Of course it would be second hash as hashes are used when transferring data as an integrity check with the remote service.